# Implementing Graphs, node/class syntax C++

Tags: c++, class, graph

I was reading a TopCoder tutorial on Graphs http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs2 and I'm trying to implement the pseudocode into C++.
My question is:
How is a class different from a struct? Which one is more appropriate for dealing with graphs? How do I pass the class node into the stack in C++? I've tried to do that, but when I pass `s.push(node(top.x+1, top.y));` it says **no matching function** found.
However if I pass like this:

```
node a;
a.x=x;
a.y=y;
s.push(a);
```

it does not generate any error. 
I'm just trying to implement and and write the solution for the problem GrafixMask (pseudocode given in the link above).
Here is my partial implementation of the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool fills[600][400];
class node
{
public:
int x;
int y;};
int doFill(int x, int y)
{
    int result=0;
    stack<node> s;
    node a;
    a.x=x;
    a.y=y;
    s.push(a);
    while(s.empty()==false)
{
    node top=s.top();
    s.pop();
    if(top.x < 0 || top.x>=600) continue;
    if (top.y < 0 || top.y >=400) continue;
    if(fills[top.x][top.y]) continue;
    fills[top.x][top.y]=true;
    result++;
    s.push(node(top.x+1, top.y));
    s.push(node(top.x, top. y+1));
    s.push(node(top.x, top.y-1));
    s.push(node(top.x-1, top.y));

}
return result;
}
int main()
{

for(int i=0; i < 599; i++)
    for(int j=0; j < 399; j++)
        fills[i][j]=false;

}
```

Comment: `struct` is just a `class` with all its members `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `node` class doesn't have a constructor that takes two integers. If you want to construct nodes that way you will need to have:

```
class node
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    node() : x( 0 ), y( 0 ) {}
    node( int pX, int pY ) : x( pX ), y( pY ) {}
};
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but what if I need another constructor for just passing a node directly into a stack? 's.push(a)' ? Also is this constructor also acceptable? ` node(int pX, int pY)
        {
            x=pX;
            y=pY;
        } `

Comment: it worked for the the subsequent calls, not the first call (where I just do just s.push(a)) refer to my question above. i.e. it fixed the error, but now the first one doesn't work. So that means I need another constructor, right?

Comment: How doesn't it work? It looks like you may need a new question. No you don't need a new constructor. You didn't have a constructor before so you couldn't call `node( int, int )`, in that first scenario you are calling the default constructor which will be fine here.

Comment: Sorry, what it says now is: "No matching function for call to node::node()' on the line where I declared node 'a'.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. You lose the default if you define you're own, so you need to define `node() : x( 0 ), y( 0 ) {}`